# Rails not loading the CSS from the correct Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem with referencing to the stylesheet contained in the assets/stylehsheets folder. Here is my layout implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>iOSScreencast</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min", :media => "all" %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the page it shows that it is looking for the "bootstrap.min" in assets folder. The asset pipeline is enabled.

Comment: This is how the assets pipeline works. It will treat all the assets as they are kept directly under assets directory.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html - good information here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to load in bootstrap through the asset pipeline.

To do this go to your `app/assets/application.css` file and add: `require 'bootstrap.min'` above the other requires in the file.

The advantage of doing it this way is that Bootstrap is compiled in with the rest of your application CSS, which makes the loading of your page generally faster.

Comment: I placed the bootstrap.min in assets/stylesheets and then in application.css I added *= require 'bootstrap.min'. When I run it get an error saying could not find bootstrap.min.css.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be to use the [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass), which you can include by using `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.4.0'`
 in your gemfile. Then you don't need to explicitly state it in your stylesheets. Instead, use a file for your custom styles:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom", :media => "all" %>
```

And then in custom.css.sass, use the @import directive to include bootstrap:

```
@import "bootstrap"
```

That'll be the easiest way to include Bootstrap in your app.